# React Hooks: saving state from one modal to another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-native

I am trying to make a Todo List creater with 2 nested modals. Each one of the modals passes a state to the Todo Component which is then published in the `App.js`. The `App.js` has an initial hook state for `showModal1` as `false`, but it changes to `true` when I press the button to open the `Modal1`.

The first modal (`Modal1`) is suposed to pass the `task` state to the second modal (`Modal2`).

```
    import React,{useState} from 'react';
    import {StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, TextInput, Modal} from 'react-native';
    import {AntDesign} from '@expo/vector-icons';
    import Modal2 from './Modal2';

function Modal1(props) {
    const [showModal2, setShowModal2] = useState(false)
    const [task, setTask] = useState('')

    const toggleShowModal2 = (task) => {
        setShowModal2(!showModal2);     
    }

    function handleTask(value) {
        setTask(value)
    }

        return(
            <View behavior='padding'>
                <Modal animationType='slide' visible={showModal2} onRequestClose={toggleShowModal2}>
                    <Modal2 closeModal={toggleShowModal2}/>
                </Modal>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.closeModal}>
                    <AntDesign name='close' size={24} color='black'/>
                </TouchableOpacity>

                <View>
                    <Text>First Step</Text>

                    <Text>Task</Text>
                    <TextInput placeholder='What is the task?' value={task} onChangeText={handleTask}/>
                </View>
                <View>   
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => toggleShowModal2(task)}>                                   
                            <AntDesign name='arrowright' size={40} color='black'/>           
                    </TouchableOpacity> 
                </View>                             
            </View>
    );
};
```

And the second modal should be able to pass the `time` state and then create the Todo with the state values.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, KeyboardAvoidingView, TouchableOpacity, TextInput, ScrollView} from 'react-native';
import {AntDesign} from '@expo/vector-icons';

function Modal2(props) {
    const [time, setTime] = useState('')
  
    function handleTime(value) {
        setTime(value)
    }

    function createTodo(){
        const list = {task, time};  
        setTask('')
        setTime('')
        
        props.addList(list);
        props.closeModal();
    } 

        return(
            <View behavior='padding'>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.closeModal}>
                    <AntDesign name='close' size={24} color='black'/>
                </TouchableOpacity>

                <View>
                    <Text>Second Step</Text>

                    <Text>Time</Text>
                    <TextInput placeholder='When are you going to do it?' value={time} onChangeText={handleTime}/>
                </View>
                <View>   
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={createTodo}>                                    
                            <AntDesign name='arrowright' size={40} color='black'/>           
                    </TouchableOpacity> 
                </View>                             
            </View>
    );
};
```

However, whenever I try to publish the Todo, the following error pops up:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: task
```

I am new to React (and React Hooks) and I don't know if it is possible to save state from one function to another in a similar way.

Comment: From where you are sending `task`. In the code I can't see

Comment: I am supposed to be sending it from  toggleShowModal2 when passing it the task as an argument. But I don't know if I am doing it right

Comment: Pass in as props for `task` just the way you do for `closeModal `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access variables defined in another component, you need to pass them as props,

so you can pass the variables as props in `Modal1`

```js
...
  <Modal2 closeModal={toggleShowModal2} task={task} setTask={setTask} />
...
```

and access them in `Modal2` like so,

```js
   function createTodo(){
        const { task, setTask } = props;

        const list = { task, time };  
        setTask('')
        setTime('')
        
        props.addList(list);
        props.closeModal();
    }
```